# Conversion of ByteBuffer in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to convert the following code to C# from Android (Java)?

```
ByteBuffer bb;

Type = bb.GetInt();
```

I tried to change this to C# as

```
Type = bb.Int;
```

but I am getting wrong values. Please let me know how to convert Java code to C# code

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Nio.ByteBuffer/

You can use

```
(int)(bb.Get());
```

Get the value as a sbyte and cast to integer.

Comment: What values are showing, and what values do you expect?