# Xamarin Android Converting Java.Nio.Buffer to byte[] (or any other array/string)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently stuck trying to convert a Java.Nio.ByteBuffer to an array or a string in a Xamarin Android App.

```
byte[] outputBytes = new byte[16];
Java.Nio.Buffer outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.Wrap(outputBytes);
//... filling buffer (using tflite model)
byte[] bufferBytes = ???
```

How can I get the content of the buffer?

Apparently there is a function like `buffer.array()`, but it doesn't work here.

So if anyone has an idea how i can make this work or any other way, help would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17354891 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/1252468

Comment: Not a duplicate. Suggestions in first link don't work due to working in another environment (I guess), which is exactly the problem here.

Comment: Second one too, I'm not writing plain java code, I can't access the methods mentioned.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/q/43117553 or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28763/efficient-conversion-of-bytearray-to-byte?

Comment: The first one actually looks like it might help, but I'm getting this with every method I tried: Error CS1061 "Buffer" does not contain a definition for "GetFloat", and no accessible GetFloat extension method that accepts a first argument of type "Buffer" could be found (a using directive or assembly reference may be missing).

Comment: ByteBuffer provides a method of GetFloat(Int32), have you tried that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Java.Nio.ByteBuffer?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it gives me the error shown above. `"Buffer" does not contain a definition for "GetFloat"`

Comment: Change Java.Nio.Buffer to var, then you could use GetFloat method. `byte[] outputBytes = new byte[16];
            var outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.Wrap(outputBytes);
            //... filling buffer (using tflite model)
            var bufferBytes = outputBuffer.GetFloat(2);`